# How do you use the Html.BeginFrom method when passing attributes to your controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

First of all, I'm fairly certain that this is already answered, and I'm sorry that it's most likely a re-post, but I can't find the answer right now. Zzz.

Here is my razor code (stripped of non-essentials):

```
@model SurveyApp.Models.LoginModel
@{
    var x = ViewBag.Culture; //x gets populated with "en-CA"
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { culture = x, id = "login-form" }))
{
    //...
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('login-form').submit()">Submit</a>
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is all of the relevant code, because in my [httppost]login method, I am getting null in the second parameter.

Here is the login prototype (or whatever you call it):

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string culture)
{
    //...
}
```

Am I using the attribute parameter of the Html.BeginForm call improperly?

Comment: You should put those as hidden form fields.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that. It worked. I'll mark your question right if you wanna bother with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put those as hidden form fields. The attributes on a `form` tag don't get submitted unless its the URL.